# MongoMapper Disable Embedded ID

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

Is it possible to disable _id for embedded documents?

For example if have a parent with an embedded child document. it seems kind of pointless for the child to have an id if i don't intend to reference the child from anywhere else.

```
class Parent
  include MongoMapper::Document
  one :child
  key :name
end

class Child
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :name
end

parent = Parent.new(:name => 'parent',
  :child => Child.new(:name => 'child'))

puts parent.to_json

{"id":"4ebeddde51d9e56dcb000006","name":"parent",
"child":{
    "id":"4ebeddde51d9e56dcb000005",
    "name":"child"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember there being talk at one point of removing the _id field for embedded one.  Best bet would be to patch it yourself and then send a pull request.

Otherwise, there isn't a config option to remove the id.  You might be able to over-write to_mongo, if you were adventurous.